# using move_base recovery for initial pose estimation

Tags: navigation, move-base, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want my robot to find its initial pose on its own rather than providing it with rviz "2d pose estimate". For that I already figured out that you can call AMCLs /global_localization service, whicht distributes the particles over the whole map. Second I'd need to rotate the robot. Therefore move_base already has the recovery behaviour, but how to trigger that? I know there is the C++ API, but isn't there a service call for that? Something that smoothly integrates with move_base resp. nav stack? Or can I use the actionlib for that? Anything any trigger despite the cpp api?

I'm wondering for a long time why there isn't something out there for initial pose estimation with the widely used combination of amcl and move_base. Are you guys all using the rviz-button? all the time you start demos?

**Update 1**

As I could not find an answer to this, I wrote a node triggering a recovery-behaviour similar to the [move_base.cpp](https://github.com/strawlab/navigation/blob/master/move_base/src/move_base.cpp) implementation. However those behaviours ([rotate_recovery](http://wiki.ros.org/rotate_recovery), [clear_costmap_recovery](http://wiki.ros.org/clear_costmap_recovery)) need the global and local costmap as parameters. Just creating your own as suggested in the code snipples from the wiki doesnt seem to work as intended since those maps are not the ones used by move_base: Running *clear_costmap_recovery* then does not clear the costmap used by move_base. **However**, and this is strange, *rotate_recovery* sometimes is not carried out due to potential collision. How can there be collisions if the costmap is empty? Or IS there a connection between a costmap you create and name ('local_costmap', 'global_costmap') and the ones used by move_base? This is confusing ...

An alternative solution would be to use *actionlib* and send *move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionGoal*, but how can I tell move_base to just use the local planner and ignore the global one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151526/using-move_base-recovery-for-initial-pose-estimation/) by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2014-04-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) on 2014-05-22**:
so .. nobody has the problem of initial pose estimation with amcl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

What robot are you using?

In my case, I'm working with Turtlebot II robots. I avoid using the rviz-button on my demos by using first the autocking sequence. Turtlebot have a docking (battery recharger) with infra-red emitters and the robot base have IR-receptors (http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki/Tutorials/Testing%20Automatic%20Docking). You can make the robot to search and find this base automatically. I take advantage of this by using the dock position as reference (putting it in an known place on the map) When the robot reach it, it publish a message to the topic 'initialpose' (PoseWithCovarianceStamped) with the reference position and AMCL now can work normally.

Maybe this is not precisely what you are searching to do, but what I recommed is that you search for a way in which therobot reaches a known position looking for some kind of landmark first, and use that reference to give the AMCL algorithm the initial position. I think that without some help (initial position), the AMCL probably will not work.

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Hdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5773/carlos-hdz/) with karma: 103 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) on 2014-04-10**:
Thanks, landmarks are one way to do it. But I want to keep it generic as the demo scenario changes often.

**Comment by [jiashiwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/26780/jiashiwei/) on 2017-07-18**:
good advice !